# How to extract .bin files?

Tags: android, bin

I want to open the saved file of the game I am playing in android and add some coins to it.

I only see this 2 files **data001.bin** and **sys.bin**. I tried to extract it using several .bin extractor but still nothing works.

Can someone suggest how can i open this files?

Comment: Is this a game you are developing or one that you are simply playing?

Comment: .bin is not a standardised format. It can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer*: **not feasible**.

*Long answer*: **.bin** files are binary files, ie, memory contents are dumped as is on disk.
Any edit you make is quite likely to corrupt the file.

Apart from that, the developer will most certainly have obfuscated the coin count, so you'll be spending ages just to find the variable.